# Easy way for user to resubmit a webform

Tags: webforms, civicrm

My users are clicking on an emailed link from CiviCRM to complete a webform, which when completed and submitted adds contacts to CiviCRM.  I'd like them to be able to have an  easy way of submitting the webform again without having to go back to the email, find the link and start over. This is because they are submitting details of one household per webform, and may have (say) 6 household they want to submit.  I'm thinking that after submission they simply go back to the start of the webform - the problem is that to do that I'd need the url they clicked on, which has a couple of contact parameters in it.  I can't find that in the tokens that are available, unfortunately.
(question moved to civicrm.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hi Andy - this is a 'civi' answer, so maybe better to shift it across. if you are using a checksum, then iirc we can grab a new checksum form and the cid from form1 and pass that through to form2 etc

Comment: Ah OK didn't know that, will follow up, thanks. And move this over - I was thinking there was a webform solution rather than a Civi one

Comment: i will add above as answer meanwhile so this Q has an A.

Comment: moved question to CiviCRM SE.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer will probably be fleshed out when it is moved to the civicrm channel)

If you are using a checksum from civimail, then you can 'daisy-chain' forms by enabling the checksum field and contact ID on form 1, and then use those as tokens in the path used after the submission so that info is passed through to form2 etc